# Check if certain color exists on an object from within scss

Tags: angular, sass

```
$topic-colors: (
    1: rgb(141, 211, 199),
    2: rgb(240, 240, 76),
    3: rgb(190, 186, 218),
    4: rgb(251, 128, 114),
    5: rgb(128, 177, 211),
    6: rgb(253, 180, 98),
    7: rgb(179, 222, 105),
    8: rgb(245, 183, 215),
    9: rgb(217, 217, 217),
    10: rgb(188, 128, 189),
);
```

I have these topic colors, in regard to that I'm also using :hover state in blue. In case if there are fewer than 10 topics, use color blue if it doesn't exist on that particular object.

If the color blue exists within any of these 10 objects, use color black.

Is this one doable with scss? Should I add any functionality in the TS file as well?

Comment: I didn't get the point. In which case do you want to apply the `black` color?

Comment: Let's say if a color from number 1 will be used, my code should check if said color is not already being used in  either an array, or in template (not sure how angular fully works and what is possible in this case) Let's call it Array<Topics>, there I would either have some property to set color, or I can choose to do so in the template, I need some suggestions on this one.

Comment: You cannot do this type of logic on SCSS, the style doesn't know who is using the class or something else. You should do some logic and apply a class with some condition (`ngClass`)